# In a React form, why do we set (for example) value={this.state.task} in the input tag?

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, state

I cannot understand why we set the value={this.state.task} when it is just an empty string, and how exactly the flow of data goes from the input value and then to the state.

When we first set the value, it's basically an empty string. But when I try to actually set  value='' , the input field does not function properly on the rendered page.

I get that onChange we set the state to the corresponding name and value, and that that's how the data is flowing into the state. But then why does it not work when, again, we just set value='' ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import uuid from 'uuid/v4';

export class NewTodoForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
       task: ""
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }
  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.createTodo({ ...this.state, id: uuid() });
    this.setState({ task: "" });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor='task'>New Todo</label>
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='New Todo'
            id='task'
            name='task'
            // why is this {this,state.task} ?
            value={this.state.task}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <button>Add Todo</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default NewTodoForm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `value` is setting ... well the value of the input. By doing this `value={this.state.task}` basically you are connecting your input with the component's state and with the lifecycle of the React component. So basically whenever you change your component's state that has the input from anywhere (even programmatically), React will be able to update the input correctly and there won't be any bugs or weird stuff happening.

In the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) it is explained very well. They are doing this **controlled component** ...

> An input form element whose value is controlled by React in this way is called a “controlled component”.

... so that the state of the React component to be the only 'source of truth', meaning to prevent weird bugs and undesired behaviour.

> Since the `value` attribute is set on our form element, the displayed value will always be `this.state.value`, making the React state the source of truth.

It is always a good practice to have one source of truth and not many. In this case if you leave the input's value to be different from the component's state, you are making more than one source of truths and thus exposing your app to bugs.

Comment: I think I get it. So basically, the flow of data is going like this:
1) The initial value of `value` is an empty string (from state).
2) Then the user begins typing, and `onChange()` is called and the state is updated to the new value of `value`.

I guess my real question is, when the user is typing in the input field, is that value coming now from the state or what is stored temporarily as they are typing in the input field?

Comment: I think my confusion is also coming from my understanding of how the input field works. As far I understand, it only obtains the value from the state when it first loads, then it's just what the user inputs into the input field and then that's pushed to the state. Is it basically refreshing each time to get that value from the state each time the user types in a character?