# Why an input value should receive the state in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I´ve already understood that when we want to update the state at the same time a change happens in the input we do this:

```
    const { name, value } = target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
  };
```

but why do need to set the state as the value of input?

```
             <input
                type="text"
                name="email"
                value={ email }
                onChange={ this.handleChange }
              />
```

Since what we write on the input will be the same as what is going to be set to the state, why need to receive this value on the input?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59239076/in-a-react-form-why-do-we-set-for-example-value-this-state-task-in-the-inpu does this solve you problem.

Comment: https://itnext.io/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-components-in-react-5cd13b2075f9